# Importing SCSS file from index.html doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, sass, stylesheet

I'm trying to import a `SCSS` file within the `head` tags in my root `index.html` file, but it doesn't load. Instead, in `Network Chrome Dev Tools` tab I see my `SCSS` file marked in red with a status of `(canceled)`.

Any idea why? Here's how I import my `SCSS` file in `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <style>
      @import 'styles/main.scss';
    </style>
  </head>
```

Comment: Just wanted to warn you about the fact that disabling user scale may cause accessibility problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can not import `scss` file directly into a html file.

if you are using vue.

in the vue component.

code like this:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
@import 'styles/main.scss';
</style>
```

Comment: What if I need to use SCSS in my index.html specifically, as opposed to within a component? I already use SCSS in all my components, but I'd like to use some SCSS in my index.html too, is that possible?

Comment: no it's not, if you have some `global css` rules that you want to apply, you could register it into App.vue. or you could use webpack to compile the scss code to css and import it into index.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are using straight HTML, you must convert your scss into CSS with a compiler first. Your browser doesnt read scss as CSS. Compiling is easy, you can use the command line, software like Koala or prepros. If you are using Vue, do what Hank said in his response

Answer (score 0):

You can not "attach" a SASS/SCSS file to an HTML document. SASS/SCSS is a CSS preprocessor that runs on the server and compiles to CSS code that your browser understands. If you Attach your sass into your HTML file then your **Browser can't understand it.**
so don't try to use it.